# React State - Nested Object Change Delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having some trouble updating my state, let me explain to you.

My state is like this:

```
{
  single: {},
  activeStep: 0,
  disableDialog: { isOpen: false, },
  disableForm: false
}
```

In the single object I store all my form data to send to backend, to be saved at db. In past times I wasn't using nested objects, but always when I submit my state to be saved I need to set other values to undefined, like this:

```
{
  ... my form data,
  activeStep: undefined,
  disableDialog: undefined,
  disableForm: undefined
}
```

Otherwise, the request response would be 500 saying to me that `activestep`, `disableDialog` and `disableForm` ins't recognized.

What's my main problem? When I type in the form and use `setState` to change `single` (which is the nested object with more than 30 properties), I got a delay to render the changes. What is the common pattern to submit data to server? What should I do? It's a bad practice to use nested objects in state?

Comment: It's not a bad practice to have nested object in the state. But I would suggest to not set other values to `undefined`.

Instead why don't  you just submit `this.state.single` to the API? I'm assuming that you are sending the whole state to the API since you are setting other values to undefined because you don't want them in the request.

Comment: I'm sending only `this.state.single` to the server, but when I change (onChange) the this.state.single.name (example) it delays to render the changes...

Comment: Don't try to fix your server issues in the frontend. It seems like your "delay" is because you're calling setState conditional to the network request which is not a problem with React's rendering but with network delays.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me (sorry for my english). When I type in the field I don't make the request. The delay is made on this.setState, changing the single nested object.